# Minify all files of a folder and copy them to a second folder

Tags: php, regex

I would like to copy minified versions of all css-files from one folder to another folder.
How can this code be optimized?

```
$path = "dev/css/";
$path_new = "productive/css/";

if (count(glob($path_new."*.css"))) { // first delete all files in $path_new
    foreach (glob($path_new."*.css") as $f => $name) {
        $file = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME).".css";
        unlink($file);
    }
}
if (count(glob($path."*.css"))) { // create minified files
    foreach (glob($path."*.css") as $f => $name) {
        $file = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME).".css";
            $css = file_get_contents($path."/".$file);
            $css = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $css);
            $css = str_replace(': ', ':', $css);
            $css = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $css);
        file_put_contents($path_new."/".$file, $css)            
    }
}
```

Can I use the same minify code to minify JS-files?

Answer (score -2):

To delete file from server use [`unlink($fileName)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)
To write new css to file use [`file_put_contents($fileName, $css)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: @user3142695 Can you explain why you have completely changed meaning of your question? First you asked how to write to file, now you ask how to optimize code and use it fro JS too... WRONG!

Comment: I asked both questions and just updated the post, cause you gave the answer of a part of the post. So why are you asking for an explanation AND downgrade the post at the same time?

Comment: @Justinas: Wrong. All three questions were part of the original post